# LWC: Lightning-record-edit-form onsuccess is not firing in community site

Tags: lightning-web-components, customer-community, experience-cloud

I have built a Lightning-record-edit-form using LwC and placed it in community site, the data is getting displayed however the onsuccess method is not firing.

Below is the LWC code:

```
  <lightning-card title="View Record">
        <lightning-record-view-form if:false={editMode} object-api-name="Account" record-id="0015j000013K0lmAAC"
            layout-type="Full" columns="2" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class="example-accordion slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <template for:each={fieldsJson} for:item="fieldData">
                    <template for:each={fieldData.fieldWithSection} for:item="fieldSection">
                        <lightning-accordion-section key={fieldSection.SectionName} name={fieldSection.SectionName}
                            label={fieldSection.SectionName}>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

                                <lightning-output-field key={fieldSection.Fields}
                                    field-name={fieldSection.Fields}></lightning-output-field>
                            </div>
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </lightning-accordion>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning-button class="brand-button slds-align_absolute-center" type="submit" name="save" label="Save"></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-view-form>
    </lightning-card>
```

Below is the js:

```
@wire(getFields)
    getDetails(result) {
        const { data, error } = result;
        if (data) {
            console.log('result'+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
            let result1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.fieldsJson= result1.fieldSection;
        }
        else{
            console.log('error'+error);
        }
    }

//below is the method which is not firiing
handleSuccess(){
        console.log('clicked on save button');
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "SUCCESS!",
                    message: "Record Updated",
                    variant: "success", 
                }),  
           );    
         
    }
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing here?

Comment: The data is being displayed, but is it being updated on the back end as well? Did you try handling the possible errors with `onerror` too?